# Assigning a Math Operator to a Variable - PS

Tags: powershell

I would like to assign a math operator (+ - / *) to a variable to build dynamic expressions.

For example:

```
$operator1 = [char][byte]'043'
$operator2 = [char][byte]'045'
$calculation = [int](1 $operator1 20 $operator1 30 $operator1 100 $operator2 51)
Write-Host calculation
```

The output 100

Remembering that the variable $calculation is extensive and contains more numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `Invoke-Expression`, but please remember that this is [potentially dangerous](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

```
$operator1 = [char][byte]'043'
$operator2 = [char][byte]'045'

$calculation = Invoke-Expression -command "[int](1 $operator1 20 $operator1 30 $operator1 100 $operator2 51)"
Write-Host $calculation
```

Outputs `100`

Comment: @DiegoDias You're welcome. Btw. Being new to the platform you may not know this but it is customary to mark the question 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left of the answer. This helps others with a similar question finding it more easily.